# SQL - Compare values in column and, if similar, copy all similar values to new column

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, duplicates

Context: A company has various products with the same (or similar) name but different sizes and colors. The entire inventory is listed in a database. Products have an "Itemcode" column and a "Name" column.

What I want to do in the database is: if any Itemcode or Name values are similar, copy their itemcode to a new column called "Itemcodes". (Plural)

Example:

```
Itemcode    Name                                                Itemcodes
6POSPP040   [6POSPP040] Polystone Plain (Partner smoke)         
6POSTLN92   [6POSTLN92] Polystone Timeless (Partner Natural)    
6POSYRRB37  [6POSYRRB37] Polystone Seaside (Partner Brown)
```

```
Itemcode    Name                                                Itemcodes
6POSPP040   [6POSPP040] Polystone Plain (Partner smoke)         6POSPP040, 6POSTLN92, 6POSYRRB37
6POSTLN92   [6POSTLN92] Polystone Timeless (Partner Natural)    6POSTLN92, 6POSPP040, 6POSYRRB37
6POSYRRB37  [6POSYRRB37] Polystone Seaside (Partner Brown)      6POSYRRB37, 6POSPP040, 6POSTLN92
```

So the column "Itemcodes" would first list the products own Itemcode, followed by the itemcodes of similar products based on name and/or itemcode.

I've looked into CONCAT and COALESCE but I am unsure how to implement these. Basically it needs to check the "Name" column, recognize that in this case the value "Polystone" has 3 variants and then list all itemcodes in the third column.

I've tried:

```
select * 
from product_table 
where itemcode in (select itemcode from product_table 
                   group by itemcode 
                   having count(*) > 1)
```

```
SELECT
    CONCAT("Selecting Col1 or 2", CAST("Col1" OR "Col2" AS string)) AS relevantinfo,
FROM 
    table
```

`COALESCE` would work in a similar manner but it doesn't seem to check values in the same column. So I'm stuck.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit: Added DBMS tag.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT()` is what you need to use to compute your Items code column. However the part in which you want  `it needs to check the "Name" column, recognize that in this case the value "Polystone" has 3 variant`  sounds like fuzzy logic deduplication which is kind of hard to achieve.

Comment: you need to state what criterias define similarities clearly ...